# How to prevent users from performing cut and delete operations on images in ckeditor designer on clientside?

Tags: javascript, html, image, ckeditor, ckeditor.net

I have some text and images in ckeditor designer,now i can allow users to change text and move it around the editor but i don't want to allow users to perform **cut**(by ctrl + x or by rightclick->cut) or **delete** operations on images present in ckeditor,however they can move images in ckeditor.

How can i  stop users on clientside from performing cut  and delete operations on images in ckeditor?

To get a better idea about moving images in ckeditor,check the images below.

Here **Component 1** is an image

[image]

I've moved my image from line 1 to line 3

[image]

Comment: No idea but I'm extremely curious: why would you want this?

Comment: I'm working on a small module in a project in which some text would be pre loaded with few images in ckeditor,now we don't want the users to delete the images placed in the ckeditor.

To add more details, it would be like a form where few images and text would be provided by us and some text and images will be added by users.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I have exactly the problem. My use case is that our editor have a widget at the top which is used by the editor to input meta data about the rest of the document. So this widget should always be located at the top of the page, so the user should not be able to "cut" it away.

Comment: @MTilsted : no I didn't found a solution to it